# Save the geovoronoi result to file

Tags: python, geopandas, voronoi-thiessen

I try to use geovoronoi in my tasks, following the example from the link [on Github](https://github.com/WZBSocialScienceCenter/geovoronoi). But I can't figure out how to properly save the result to shp or any other vector format. The dataframe didn't work for me. I am using Python and jupyter notebook.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union
from geovoronoi.plotting import subplot_for_map, plot_voronoi_polys_with_points_in_area
from geovoronoi import voronoi_regions_from_coords, points_to_coords
points = gpd.read_file('pnts.shp')
border = gpd.read_file('brdr.shp')
brdr = border.to_crs(epsg=32636)
pnts = points.to_crs(border.crs)
brdr_shape = cascaded_union(brdr.geometry)
pnts_coord = points_to_coords(pnts.geometry)
region_polys, region_pts = voronoi_regions_from_coords(pnts_coord, brdr_shape)
fig, ax = subplot_for_map(figsize=(12, 10))
voronogo = plot_voronoi_polys_with_points_in_area(ax, brdr_shape, region_polys, pnts_coord, region_pts)
plt.show()
#mygdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pnts_coord, brdr_shape)
#mygdf.to_file(voronoi.shp')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`region_polys` is a dictionary like:

```
{0: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x7f...>,
 1: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x7f...>,
 2: .....}
```

Therefore, you can save the region polygons using the following lines:

```
region_polys, region_pts = voronoi_regions_from_coords(pnts_coord, brdr_shape)

gs = gpd.GeoSeries(region_polys)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gs, columns=["geometry"])
gdf.to_file("voronoi.shp")
```

Comment: I got a warning:
`\anaconda3\envs\geo\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py:234: FutureWarning: pandas.Int64Index is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.Index with the appropriate dtype instead.
  pd.Int64Index,`

Comment: It is just warning about geopandas. No need to worry.

Comment: I changed your code to

`gs = gpd.GeoSeries(region_polys)` 
`gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gs, columns=["geometry"]).set_crs("epsg:32636")` 
`gdf.to_file('voronoi.shp', index = False)` 
and it works for me. Thank you!